# How do I prevent a jQuery 'click' event from firing when mouse is dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have panels that collapse/expand when you click on the panel heading.

But there's also text in these headings that will often need to be selected for copy/paste.

How do I prevent the jQuery event `.slideUp` and `.slideDown` from firing when a mouse is clicked for the purpose of dragging to select text?

```
var currentlyAnimating = false;
function setAnimationOff() {
    currentlyAnimating = false;
}
function setAnimationOn(this_animation) {
    currentlyAnimating = this_animation;
    setTimeout(setAnimationOff, 650);
}
function panelAccordionAnimation(this_heading) {
    var _meta_div = this_heading.nextAll('.panel-body, .course-heading');
    var _button = this_heading.find('.heading-container-btn.right-most');
    if (_meta_div.css('display') == 'none') {
        this_heading
            .animate({
                borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
                borderBottomRightRadius: 0}, 200);
        _button
            .animate({
                borderBottomRightRadius: 0}, 200);
        _meta_div.delay(200).slideDown();
    } else {
        _meta_div.slideUp();
        this_heading.delay(200)
            .animate({
                borderBottomLeftRadius: 14,
                borderBottomRightRadius: 14}, 200);
        _button.delay(200)
            .animate({
                borderBottomRightRadius: 14}, 200);
    }
}
_student_details.on('click', '.top-heading.blue', function(e) {
    var _heading = $(e.target);
    if (_heading == currentlyAnimating) {
        return false;
    }
    panelAccordionAnimation(_heading);
    setAnimationOn(_heading);
});
_student_details.on('click', '.top-heading.blue .heading-container-title', function(e) {
    var _heading = $(e.target).parent();
    if (_heading == currentlyAnimating) {
        return false;
    }
    panelAccordionAnimation(_heading);
    setAnimationOn(_heading);
});
```

I have separate click events for the text in the heading because I want the collapse/expand to happen if you click the title, but not when you drag your mouse on the title.

Comment: Instead of "how to prevent the event from firing", think along the lines of "how to ignore the event when a certain condition is true".

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of the code you're using?

Comment: Why don't you use link in heading? It can be clicked / selected... Just like [bootstrap accordion](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion) does.

Comment: I didn't even know bootstrap came with its own accordion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind a `mousedown` handler to the element, inside there, store the coordinates of the mouse. In the click event, compare those mouse coordinates to the current ones, if they're not the same, the mouse has moved, and you can prevent the rest of the handler's code from running:

```
$( yourEl ).on( {
  mousedown: function( evt ) {
    $( this ).data( 'mCoords', { x: evt.pageX, y: evt.pageY } );
  },
  click: function( evt ) {
    var $this = $( this );

    if ( $this.data( 'mCoords' )[ 'x' ] !== evt.pageX 
      || $this.data( 'mCoords' )[ 'y' ] !== evt.pageY
    ) {
      // the mouse was moved
      return true;
    }

    // your code
  }
} );
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/850Ly3rs/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have serveral ways to choose from to determine if the user is trying to close the accordion or just select some text.

1. You can check the time distance between the `mousedown` event and the `mouseup`. On the `mousedown` event, set a boolean (Lets call it `quick`) to `true`, and set a `timeout` function to 80ms (minimal human reaction time) to set it to false. On your `mouseup` event, check for that boolean before firing `.slideUp` or `.slideDown`.
2. Check if the user has selected a text within your heading. You can do this with `window.getSelection().anchorNode === e.target` if this test is `true` some text has been selected in your heading and you can decide to not trigger `.slideUp` or `.slideDown` when the `mouseup` event comes.

While I would say that both of the options above are sort of a hack, I don't think there is another way to distinguish between a click that has the intention to collapse the heading to a click just for selection.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple.

Fire the event for click with `mouseup`.

You can use mouseup like this:

```
$( "#target" ).mouseup(function() {
   alert( "Handler for mouseup() called." );
})
```

Have a variable `var check = false`;

Turn it to true only when a `mouseup` is registered.

Add this check to all the functions and fire the only if `check = true`

Comment: It will still fire after the text has been selected. I'm trying to prevent all firing if the mouse is moved at all between `mousedown` and `mouseup`

Comment: @LXXIII Yes, have a check for validation. Turn it to true only if you have a mouseup event. If that check is true only then fire the functions for click.

Comment: @billyonecan I asked him to add a conditional in the click event that he has. and it would solve the problem.

Comment: i don't understand how adding a mouseup handler solves the problem

Comment: @billyonecan Once a user clicks on a div one function is called. Instead of using click I asked him to use a mouseup. So on mouseup that function should be called.